# How to replace values in one column with string containing "xxx", with value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, replace, where-clause

I am trying to replace values in Col1 with the corresponding row value in Col2 if Col1 contains the string "Local".

I've tried the 3 variations and neither seem to work.

```
df = df['Col1'].replace(['Col1'].str.contains("Local"),["Col2"])
```

&

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].isin(['Local']), 'Col1'] = ['Col2']
```

&

```
df3['Client Name_x']=df3['Client Name_y'].where(df3['Client Name_x'].isin(['Local']),df3['Client Name_x'])
```

Neither of these pieces of code have the desired outcome...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].mask(df['Col1'].str.contains('Local'), df['Col2'])
```

If you don't want case sensitive you can pass `case=False` in `str.contains`

Another approach could be:

```
df['Col1'] = np.where(df['Col1'].str.contains('Local'), df['Col2'], df['Col1'])
```